# Use relative clause or adverbial clause?

Tags: sentence-structure, exam-questions

> Garbage cans would be picked up from the narrow alleys____ ran behind the rows of houses.  (From an ACT English test)

Regarding the blank, which answer is more acceptable? 1. that; 2. since they?

Though the answer is " that, " which I can understand why; but why "since they" is not ok? I comprehend it as a cause adverbial clause and "they" refers to garbage cans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in determining the two clause types: with "that" it is a relative clause in the sentence, with "since they" an adverbial clause.

"Since they" is **syntactically** valid in this context but not **semantically**. That is to say, with "since they" the sentence is grammatical, but doesn't make much sense. If you want to make a I'd also put a comma before "since", but it is optional.

> Garbage cans would be picked up from the narrow alleys, since they ran behind the rows of houses.

"Since" means because here. And this sentence tells you *Because the alleys ran behind the rows of houses, garbage cans would be picked up from the narrow alleys.* It doesn't make sense, does it? There is no causality as "since" seems to suggest. That is the reason of the two options you should choose "that".

Comment: Can I regard that "they" is referring to "garbage cans，”  I think that makes more sense.

Comment: @CharlieWang Barely. Garbage cans don't "run behind the rows of houses" unless on a slope or somebody kicks them. To me "ran behind the rows of houses" clearly points to "the narrow alleys."